# Asynchronously Updating State After A Function Call Returns API Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to asynchronously update the state when my fetchWeather function is called from my WeatherProvider and makes an axios request to a weather api. The results of my request are mapping to a forecast variable inside the fetchWeather function.

I want to set the new state of my forecast array to be the forecast results from my fetchWeather function. I've tried using setState in various ways but I still can't manage to update the state. What am I getting wrong here?

```
import React from 'react' 
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'

export const WeatherContext = React.createContext();

export class WeatherProvider extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        context: {
            input: '',
            forecast: [],
            fetchWeather: WeatherProvider.fetchWeather
        }
    }

    this.fetchWeather = this.fetchWeather.bind(this)
}

fetchWeather = (term) => {
    let QUERY = term;
    const KEY = `key`
    let URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${QUERY}&appid=${KEY}`

    axios.get(URL)
    .then( res => {
        const forecast = _.flattenDeep(Array.from(res.data.list).map((cast) => [{
            date: cast.dt_txt, 
            temp_min: cast.main.temp_min,
            temp_max: cast.main.temp_max,
            group: cast.weather[0].main,
            detail: cast.weather[0].description,
            icon: cast.weather[0].icon
        }]) )

        this.setState(() => {
           forecast: forecast
        },() => { console.log(forecast, this.state.context.forecast) 
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <WeatherContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state.context, fetchWeather: this.fetchWeather }} >
            { this.props.children }
        </WeatherContext.Provider>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state should be set like,

```
 .then( res => {
    ...
        let tempConetxt = {...this.state.context}
    tempContext.forecast = forecast;
        this.setState({context: tempContext},() => { console.log(forecast, this.state.context.forecast)
```

Now value will updated in the context field of state.

Comment: Thank you, I checked and this setState was already inside of my axios request.

Comment: Ok, then can you confirm whether the .then is getting called by adding a console.log inside .then.

Comment: this.setState(() => { forecast: forecast},() => { console.log(forecast, this.state.context.forecast) logs as : 
(39) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] [] 
so  the forecast is there but the state doesn't update

Comment: Pls check the changed answer. I think the state is getting updated but the console.log ing of state value was wrong

Comment: Changed it to this.state.forecast and it returns undefined.

Comment: Ok,last and final, pls change the setstate like the updated answer :)

Comment: Yes, that worked. I think I'm missing the nuance of what just happened. Sorry to be daft but why does that work and my solution didn't? Also, will this asynchronously update my state when the function runs. I thought it needed to be a function?

Comment: This was the way i added my first answer though, and setstate param not necessarily has to be a function. It can be an object which will be merged with the state value. And yes this will be asynchronously updated.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the aswer for the stack overflow community so that the question will be shown as answered

Comment: So that actually didn't solve my problem because forecast is an array inside of the context object which initialized state. So what this.state.forecast is loggingis the forecast is inside of the fetchWeather method. When I log this.state.context.forecast it is still an empty array. this.state.context is what my provider is using as the
{ this.props.children }

Comment: Pls check the latest code now. updated for updating the state value in context

Comment: Yaaas, That's it!  So I needed create a variable that held the value of the current state of the context and then set the forecast property to be the forecast results. setState uses just context here and is set to the variable I created ...

Comment: Yes, two things you need to remember is setState is a merge operation to the first level objects in state and state values are immutable so you will have to spread(... operator) it and use it.